# How to use Clausius-Mossotti equation to determine the molecular structure of a compound?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-structure, polarity

A question in my exam came as follows:

> Explain the Clausius-Mossotti equation. How is it used in establishing the molecular structure of a compound?

I have studied the Clausius-Mossotti equation and I know how to derive its expression. I know that it deals with the Dielectric Constant, Molecular weight of the given molecule, the Density of the dielectric or medium between the two parallel plates of condenser, Avogadrov Number, and Molecular polarizability of medium or dielectric. However, none of my textbooks talk about how to actually use this equation to determine the actual molecular structure of any compound that is under study. My professor has not taught this either. I was unable to find any external sources that talk about this as well.

Could someone please explain the steps on (or concept about) how to determine (or establish) the molecular structure of a compound after knowing the required values?

Comment: The question asks 'how it is used in establishing the structure', not in determining it, so you would use it to estimate the molecular weight.

Comment: @porphyrin  Ohh Thank you for clarifying the difference. If you don't mind, an elaborated answer will be so helpful. 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has become a question more on the mathematics of the Clausius-Mossoti relation and not the concepts behind it considering OP has an understanding on the different parameters required.

Comment: @Safdar  After reading your comment, I posted this question on Mathematics Stackexchange. They are saying that it is about establishing '**Molecular Structure**' and not about deriving the equation itself. So, they closed my question and asked me to post this question on Chemistry Stackexchange. As you had already closed my question here too, I would request you to kindly guide me that in which forum should I post this question? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant that once poryphyrin told you that it is used to estimate the molecular weight and as you said you knew about all the conditions and how to obtain them, I thought all you had to do was plug in values. However I do not know about this and was going from the statement in your question. I am sorry about the inconvenience for having to ask in Math SE..